# Why is Pytorch Lightning `validation_step` executed more oftener than defined in `val_check_interval`?

Tags: python, pytorch-lightning

I have a dataset with 20 rows and want to have four times a [Pytorch Lightning](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/trainer.html#:%7E:text=trainer%20%3D%20trainer(val_check_interval%3D0.25)) `validation_step` called on this dataset. I am setting my

```
`val_check_interval=0.25`, 
`eval_batch_size=4` and 
`num_train_epochs=1`
```

. Thats my validation_step:

```py
def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    print("+"* 30)
```

What I expect is to see the `print` command four times because of the `val_check_interval` instead the print appears seven times. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value num_train_epochs to 4 to print 4 times. Currently validation_step is being called 20 times as the value of epoch is 1

val_check_interval and eval_batch_size don't determine the validation_step calls.

use val_check_interval for validation > 1  per training epoch
Use check_val_every_n_epoch for validation for lower frequency